# Can string lines directly inserted into XML file

Tags: java, xml, io

I get the XML text of document as a string using BufferedReader. I tried to write same XML string lines to another XML file using IO but i can't. I have following employee.xml file.

```
<employee id="1" xmlns="">
    <firstname>James</firstname>
    <lastname>Harley</lastname>
    <email>james@example.org</email>
    <department>Human Resources</department>
    <salary>1000</salary>
</employee>

<employee id="2" xmlns="">
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>May</lastname>
    <email>john@example.org</email>
    <department>Logistics</department>
    <salary>400</salary>
</employee>
```

I tried reading xml file that works well with my this method.

```
private static ArrayList<String> getXMLLines(String xmlFile) {
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> lines=new ArrayList<String>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xmlFile),"ISO-8859-1"))) {
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         if(line.contains("xmlns=\"\"")){
                System.out.println(line);
                line=line.replace("xmlns=\"\"","");
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            lines.add(line);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  lines;
}
```

The problem with me is coming in writing these string lines into XML file. How can i write these string lines to XML file ?

Comment: So basically what you want to do is copy the content of your employees.xml file to another xml file or just write the XML text you're creating into a file?

Comment: I have string lines containing XML tags in this ArrayList : ArrayList<String> lines=new ArrayList<String>();. Now, I want to write these string lines to xml file.

Comment: Why not use [Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)?  As in, `Files.write(Paths.get("data.xml"), lines)`.